# Filtering composite structures with Lens

Tags: haskell, lenses

I have a `[(a, Maybe b)]`, and want to obtain a `[(a, b)]`, with all pairs where the second element was `Nothing` filtered out.
Is there a concise way to describe this operation using lens?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How about something like

```
[('a',Just 1),('b',Nothing)]^..folded.aside _Just
```

Using `(^..)` and `folded` from `Control.Lens.Fold` and `aside` and `_Just` from `Control.Lens.Prism`.

The key is `aside`, a handy function that builds a prism working on a pair from a prism working on a component of the pair.

Answer (score 12):

Notwithstanding the ingeniousity of the Lenses, the follwoing would probably be the mark for conciseness:

```
[ (a, b) | (a, Just b) <- list ]
```

(Not to speak of readability.)

Comment: Setting aside for a moment the fact that I totally forgot Haskell had list comprehensions...

Why exactly does this also filter? I'm used to things like those telling me there's a non-exhaustive pattern. Do list comprehensions simply throw away values with non-matching constructors for algebraic types? I've never heard of that feature.

Comment: Exactly that, @Narvius. Haskell 2010 report, pg. 22: Such a list comprehension returns the list of elements produced by evaluating e in the successive environments
created by the nested, depth-first evaluation of the generators in the qualifier list. Binding of variables
occurs according to the normal pattern matching rules (see Section 3.17), and **if a match fails then that element
of the list is simply skipped over.**

Comment: When pattern matching with `<-` fails, it calls `fail` of the corresponding monad, and for lists this is `[]`.

Comment: @sdcwc Ah, good ol' Haskell. You're never far from the next powerful generalization.

Answer (score 4):

```
mapMaybe sequenceA :: [(a, Maybe b)] -> [(a,b)]
```

You need to import `Data.Traversable`, `Data.Maybe` and have a `Traversable ((,) a)` instance. I leave figuring how does this work to the reader.

Comment: That's a fun answer.